# CQ5 debug bundles using eclipse won't halt

Tags: eclipse, debugging, bundle, aem

I created a bundle that I already uploaded, but I would like to debug it.
I started the server with debug mode:

```
java
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024M -jar AEM_6.0_Quickstart.jar
```

Then I set to the project that packaged into the bundle its remote debugging configuration. But when I set the breakpoints in the project, it won't halt where it needs to when the lines are executed.

Comment: Did u refer to this ? https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQ5HowToSetupRemoteDebuggingWithEclipse.html

Comment: Are you using linux or windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are some steps that can be helpful. Use that command line to start your CQ instance.

```
java -jar cq5-author-4502.jar -fork -forkargs -- -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=59865,suspend=n,server=y -Xmx1520m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:-UseSplitVerifier
```

I have simple title component in which I am calling some service method. And applied some breakpoints in service. I have multi-module eclipse project practice. Setup eclipse debug configurations as shown below :

[image]

Inside source add project's module as shown below :

[image]

Click on the debug button and refresh the cq page. You will see below image:
[image]

Open the Eclipse in debug prospective you can see you variables over there and page still loading as you not complete the method execution.
[image]

Hope this will Help!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace CQ_JVM_OPTS at cq5/aem directory >> crx/bin/start

```
CQ_JVM_OPTS='-server -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=30303,suspend=n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the heap size which is allocated to CQ process.
Make XX:MaxPermSize=512m and try.